# React-Native: conditional styling of child component

Tags: react-native

I've got an array full of numbers 1, 2, 3. I'm trying to map over it for each number to render a Square component. This worked fine. Now I want to conditionally style the Square component depending on the value (1, 2 or 3). I've got a syntax error on the line with 'switch' (Unexpected token) that I can't seem to spot the reason for.

```
class MainMaze extends Component {

  generateMaze() {
    const { tiles, cols, rows } = this.props.grid;
    return (
      tiles.map((sq, i) =>
        switch (sq) {
          case 3:
            return <Square style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>{sq}</Square>;
          case 2:
            return <Square style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>{sq}</Square>;
          default:
            return <Square style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}>{sq}</Square>;
        }
    );
  }
  render() {
    const { grid, position, status } = this.props;

    return (
      <View>
        <CardSection>
          <Text>{grid.cols}</Text>
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection>
          {this.generateMaze()}
        </CardSection>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    status: state.status,
    position: state.position,
    grid: state.grid
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MainMaze);
```

the Square component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Square = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.containerStyle, props.style]}>
      <Text>
        {props.children}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    elevation: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    margin: 0,
    height: 30,
    width: 30
  }
};

export { Square };
```

Comment: Can you access props from `Square` component.I mean What are your props in `Square` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax of an arrow expression function with multiple statements (taken from [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)):

`(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }`
ie, you should wrap the `switch` block with `{...}`:

`generateMaze() {
    const { tiles, cols, rows } = this.props.grid;
    return (
      tiles.map((sq, i) => {
        switch (sq) {
          case 3:
            return <Square style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>{sq}</Square>;
          case 2:
            return <Square style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>{sq}</Square>;
          default:
            return <Square style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}>{sq}</Square>;
        }
      }
  ))
  }`

Comment: thanks. It also needed a semi colon after the )) but that was it.